# MSDeploy WMSVC is not working in .net environment

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy

I have a build/test server which is currently running Jenkins for my continuous integration and it also is acting as my test server where code will be deployed to once built (i hope to rectify this and seperate these at a  later date when budget allows)

I have a .NET web solution (nothing complex just Umbraco essentially) that i have in SVN and Jenkins is now building correctly. I now want to deploy it onto the same server using MSDeploy. After the build completes the package is generated but the deploy fails with the error

> ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxx"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started

Here is my msbuild parameters that Jenkins uses

```
/P:Configuration=Release 
/P:DeployOnBuild=True 
/P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
/P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish 
/P:PublishProfile=GetSomePixels 
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://build.######## 
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
/P:UserName=####### 
/P:Password=########
```

I've checked the server and the Web Management Service is running and is starting up manually

I've also gone into IIS 8 manager (server 2012) and checked the "Allow Remote Connections" box under "Management Service". Restarted IIS and the WMSVC and still not working.

If i go to https://myserver.co.uk:8172/MsDeploy.axd in a browser it resolves (gives you the warning about an untrusted cert) and then displays a blank page.

Anyone got any ideas as to what i can do? I thought that it may be firewall related and even though it had added an exception to windows firewall for 8172 i have turned the entire firewall off to completely rulle that out and still no luck.

Have run this on the server to check its listening on the correct port

C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -a | findstr 8172
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8172           GSP-BUILD:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8172              GSP-BUILD:0            LISTENING

Comment: Ok i've resolved this. It appears you have to activate the web management service first and then install web deploy and i'd done it the other way round. I uninstalled WebDeploy and re-installed it, restarted the server and its working

Comment: make an answer from your comment. This is an important piece of advice here. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed works! Askolein gives you a good suggestion, @ian-davies

Comment: @IanDavies please please please put your comment as an answer and mark it. Spent most of friday banging my head against my desk trying to fix this and then found this answer just now. My sore head thanks you for it

Comment: I also met the same problem. When installing WebDeploy, do not choose classic installation, but choose complete installation.

Answer (score 15):

Ok i've resolved this. It appears you have to activate the web management service first and then install web deploy and i'd done it the other way round. I uninstalled WebDeploy and re-installed it, restarted the server and its working

Answer (score 4):

Agree with comment.

We had a similar issue.  Initial installation even post Web Management Service activation appeared to be incomplete.  In our case, even though the service said it was started we couldn't achieve the "green tick" when testing the connection from the Publish dialog when defining a profile.

Reinstalling WebDeploy 3.6 made it function properly.