# MSDeploy - Destination Not Reachable

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-deployment, webdeploy

I have installed Web Deploy 3.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and tried to run remote publish web application through visual studio 2012. However, I got the error - Destination Not Reachable.

I read some post and checked below and still got no luck.

- Firewall was off
- Both Web Management Service and Web Deployment Agent Service were restarted and running
- Tried to open https://[server]:8172/msDeploy.axd in a browser and it is reachable. (Use default 8172)
- Tried to use http://[server]/MsDeployAgentService and it is working with Admin username/password.

Did I miss anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Maybe same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708021/msdeploy-wmsvc-not-working ?

> It appears you have to activate the web management service first and
>   then install web deploy and i'd done it the other way round. I
>   uninstalled WebDeploy and re-installed it, restarted the server and
>   its working

Answer (score 2):

I also met the same problem. When installing WebDeploy, do not choose classic installation, but choose complete installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you messed with SSL certificates this could be one of the causes as well:
https://serverfault.com/questions/613634/could-not-connect-to-remote-computer-web-deploy-error-destination-not-reachable#answer-812712